# CSS counter disabled when container queries are set

Tags: css

When trying to apply container queries to an element that also has a counter implemented I noticed the counter simply stopped working. This happens in both Firefox and Chrome.

I would think these properties are unrelated. Should this be happening?

```css
.list li { background: lightpink; }

.withContainer {
  container: thislist / inline-size;
}
@container thislist (max-width: 600px) {
  .withContainer li { background: gold; }
}

.withCounter {
  counter-reset: listCount;
}
.withCounter li:after{
  content: counter(listCount);
  counter-increment: listCount;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list withContainer">
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list withContainer withCounter">
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list withCounter">
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
  </ul>
```